# Append to NSTextView and scroll

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

OK, what I need *should* have been very simple. However, I've looked everywhere and I'm not sure I've found something that works 100% (and it's something that has troubled me in the past too).

So, here we are :

- I want to be able to **append** to an `NSTextView`
- After appending, the `NSTextView` should scroll down (so that that latest appended contents are visible)

Rather straightforward, huh?

So... any ideas? (A code example that performs exactly this simple "trick" would be more than ideal...)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After cross-referencing several answers and sources (with some tweaks), here's the answer that *does* work (given  `_myTextView` is an `NSTextView` outlet) :

```
- (void)appendToMyTextView:(NSString*)text
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSAttributedString* attr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

        [[_myTextView textStorage] appendAttributedString:attr];
        [_myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([[_myTextView string] length], 0)];
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't use `_myTextView`. Use `self.myTextView` instead. The `_myTextView` method of accessing a property should only be used when you are executing the line of code millions of times in rapid succession. This is especially true when using GCD, since `self.myTextView` is thread safe (depending how it's declared).

Answer (score 14):

The `appendAttributedString` and `scrollToEndOfDocument` are available starting in OS X [10.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/appendAttributedString:) and [10.6](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/scrollToEndOfDocument:) respectively

```
extension NSTextView {
    func append(string: String) {
        self.textStorage?.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: string))
        self.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Should one worry about memory management here when the total length of the string managed by the textview gets crazy long (> 100,000 lines)? e.g., when adding lines from a log file that grows indefinitely...

Comment: @wcochran you need a custom textview for this that only has a small range of the file in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this way :

```
for (NSInteger i=1; i<=100; i++) {
    [self.textView setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",[self.textView string],@(i)]];
}

[self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([[self.textView string] length], 0)];
```

Comment: That's almost the same with my approach (with the exception being that performing tricks on an `NSTextView` from the main thread, from my experience, is actually safer if you want to avoid glitches and all sorts of unexpected behaviours...). Thanks a lot for your answer, anyway! ;-)

Comment: You used blocks, and appended the textView's text, i re-wrote it, yours is better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Swift version of Anoop Vaidya's answer

```
extension NSTextView {
    func append(string: String) {
        let oldString = self.string == nil ? "" : self.string!
        let newString = NSString(format: "%@%@", oldString, string)
        self.string = newString
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the semantics so that a newline isn't always added when you append.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a Swifti*er* solution:

```
extension NSTextView {
    func appendString(string:String) {
        self.string! += string
        self.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location:countElements(self.string!), length: 0))
    }
}
```