# Textview only shows the last query item - MacOS App

Tags: swift, macos

With the code below, I want to print query items into textview, but only the last query appears.
When I print it on the console, all are visible.

```
let url = URL(string: inputURL.string)!
    let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    if let components = components {
        if let queryItems = components.queryItems {
            for queryItem in queryItems {
                outputURL.string = "\(queryItem.name) = \(queryItem.value ?? "")"
                print("\(queryItem.name) = \(queryItem.value ?? "")")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show how you populate the text view?

Comment: [storyboard](https://prnt.sc/11gttpd) & [code](https://prnt.sc/11gtwye) @Woodstock

Comment: Is `outputURL` a `NSTextView`?

Comment: @Willeke yes NSTextView

Comment: Duplicate of [Append to NSTextView and scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172971/append-to-nstextview-and-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `NSTextView` each time you iterate through your loop.

Change this:

`outputURL.string = "\(queryItem.name) = \(queryItem.value ?? "")"`

to this:

`outputURL.string.append ("\(queryItem.name) = \(queryItem.value ?? "")")`